# What SQL query can I use to select users with only 0 products?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-analysis

I am inserting a CSV file with a large amount of data in a similar format to the screenshot below.

I'm currently trying to create an SQL query that will select all users with:

- 0 in the 'Data' column (Column E)
- 0 in the 'Min' column (Column F)
- 1 in the 'Amt' column (Column G)
- All 3 of the above need to be true for **every row of that user.**

So, if the query was ran on the data below **only** 'Steven Jones' would be selected & **not** 'Alice Baker' because 'Steven Jones' is the only user where **all** of his rows have the 0, 0, 1 I am looking for.

The SQL database consists of one table with the field names below.

Could anybody point me in the correct direction for creating the query? Thank you.

[image: Screenshot of CSV]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `having` and `group by`:

```
select userId
from table t
group by userId
having min(data) = 0 and max(data) = 0 and
       min(`min`) = 0 and max(`min`) = 0 and
       min(amt) = 1 and max(amt) = 1;
```

Comment: Would running sum(data) = 0 and sum(`min`) = 0 be quicker than running the min/max each time?

Comment: Also it should be =0 not =9 but I can't submit an edit as it's only 1 character :D

Comment: Perfect, so simple! :(

Comment: @franglais . . . I fixed the code.  As for `sum()` versus the `min()` and `max()`.  The sum would work, assuming that the values are always non-negative.  There should be minimal overhead for an additional aggregation function -- with the exception of `count(distinct)`.

Comment: hadn't thought about negatives, cunning

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, we're trying to find a set of people where they do not have a row that exists where data is non-zero, min is non-zero, and amt is non-one.

so...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(userid)
FROM mytable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid
     AND  t2.data != 0
     AND  t2.min != 0
     AND  t2.AMT != 1
)
```